# Changing date format from "20200613" to "2020-06-13"

Tags: pandas, csv

I have a data frame, df_new, with a column called "date". There are 53 entries of that exact date in the column. I am trying to figure out how to reformat it so that the date for each entry under that column shows as "2020-06-13".

Sidenote: The date in that column came from a CSV file as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `pd.to_datetime('20200613', format = '%Y%m%d')`
or

`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format = '%Y%m%d')`

Suppose that column for which you need to change the format is named `Date`
then you can create a new column named `date_conv` which contains converted date format within the same Dataframe `df` using

`df['date_conv'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format = '%Y%m%d')`

Comment: This gave me a timestamp but did not modify the data when I ran .head() of the dataframe

Comment: Wait, it worked. Thank you!!!! (I made a small typing error, my bad)